# Can I use Freeform's JavaScript plugin to alter field options on the fly?

Tags: plugin-freeform

I have a Freeform form that consists of 4 pages. On the first page, the visitor selects a date. Based on that date, the options of the select fields on page 2, 3 and 4 should change.

- Can I somehow access the posted data of page 1, on page 2?
- Can I alter the options for a Freeform checkbox field after it's been loaded? Would this cause problems when submitting the form?